# Geiger counter acoustic signal

Tags: led

I obtained a Fnirsi GC-01 Geiger counter which has a blinking LED that shows the count at the moment, but I also want an acoustic signal like a beeping or clicking sound added.

Is it possible to just solder an acoustic signal device parallel to the LED?

I will measure the voltage of that LED and provide further information soon.

Comment: It is possible but another question is will it work. Which depends on the LED circuit and the acoustic signal device and we don't know anything about either of them.

Comment: A loudspeaker "click" might be possible if it is wired *in series* with the LED. Perhaps a bit feeble. Series-connected earbud should be louder.

Answer (score 1):

Try using a piezo transducer (not a beeper with an oscillator inside it) parallel to the LED. If its clicks are not loud enough then connect the piezo parallel with the series LED and its current-limiting resistor. If the DC voltage is too high and blows up the piezo then add a capacitor in series with the piezo.

Comment: Darn, that’s even simpler than my solution. Have an upvote.

Answer (score 0):

The LED circuit will have a current limiting resistor of a couple of hundred ohms. Loudspeakers that match that aren't terribly common, but something like [this one](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/683/SM2806150-1-469420.pdf) (150 ohms) should give you a bit of a click (not very loud). If you just solder it in parallel with the LED, it may steal enough power that the LED doesn't flash: you can control the division of the power by putting a capacitor of a few µF in series with the speaker.

Alternatively, feed the signals from both sides of the LED through ~0.1 µF capacitors to a powered "computer speaker". It's best if the unswitched end of the LED is attached (through the capacitor) to the "ground" (outer) contact of the plug on the cable.

Comment: Sounds like a plan. Wouldn't it be possible to also exchange the resistor for the speaker?

Comment: @scorpionking160 No. The 150 ohms is the *impedance* of the speaker at audio frequencies. Its *resistance* will be too low.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the internals of how your Geiger counter is made, this is an educated guess. Speakers/summers/buzzers come in different varieties. The examples below assumes DC ones. Substitute 12 V for whatever voltage it's rated for.

External transistor drive from some internal IC in your Geiger counter:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fz3Upw.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Internal direct (high side) drive of LED from some internal IC:

[image: schematic]

Internal direct (low side) drive of LED from some internal IC:
[image]

To tell for sure, you need to open it and trace out a schematic around the LED. If you do, I'll update my answer with a solution that fits.

Here is an example of a DC buzzer:
https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/cui-devices/CX-0905C/671241

If you have 5 V available inside the Geiger counter, you can probably hook directly into that and no need for external power.

Comment: I will take a look. I have some knowledge about electronics, and I will also measure the voltage on the LED.